# Hibernate second level cache is not used in every case

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Using Spring Boot 2, Spring Data JPA and Hibernate. I am trying to use the second level cache of Hibernate for some entities that are never updated.

In my case, the entity `DocumentType` is related to other entities, therefore when querying one document type, Hibernate is making 4 sql queries.
When using Hibernate second level cache, the cache is used for some entities but there is still one sql query made to the database.
I want to understand why the cache is not used in one case.

This is what my entities look like:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "document_type")
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class DocumentType {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String subtypeCode;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Translation translation;

    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "business", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "document_type_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "business")
    private Set<Business> businesses;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "equivalence_id")
    private Equivalence equivalence;
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "equivalence")
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class Equivalence {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="equivalence", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<DocumentType> documentTypeList;
```

When I fetch a document type for the first time with this method:

```java
@Repository
public interface DocumentTypeRepository extends JpaRepository<DocumentType, Long> {

    DocumentType findBySubtypeCode(String subtypeCode);
```

I have the following session metrics:

```
    1704919 nanoseconds spent preparing 4 JDBC statements;
    33284024 nanoseconds spent executing 4 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    2983589 nanoseconds spent performing 4 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    1313315 nanoseconds spent performing 3 L2C misses;
```

The same document type fetched a second time gives:

```
    27855 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
    4348289 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    14421 nanoseconds spent performing 1 L2C puts;
    182655 nanoseconds spent performing 3 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
```

I would like to have 0 JDBC statements the second time but it's not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Second level cache only works when entities are retrieved by their ids, either using `EntityManager.find(...)` or internally when JPA needs to fetch related entities. Query results are never cached by default.

What you want is [Hibernate query cache](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-query-cache-work/) and the `org.hibernate.cacheable` query hint. Alternatively, you can enable Spring cache and use either the `@Cacheable` or `@CachePut` annotation.